Will Homescreen website shortcuts be gone if I switch carriers?
My wife saves a lot of websites as homescreen short cuts grouped in folders. She has an unlocked Galaxy s20 fe. I am trying to figure out if they will still be there if we switch from Verizon to visible. Thank you.

Because the location and position of Home Screen shortcuts and apps are stored on the device's storage, they will not be removed if you switch the sim card or carrier of the device.
You will, however, lose these shortcuts if you change browsers, clear app data of the browser, or uninstall the browser.

Those icons on homescreens that directly open a website are additional icons of the webbrowser app they are opened in. Therefore these icons are not changed or removed if you change (or just remove) SIM card.
Only clearing app data of the webbrowser app will erase all website icons on homescreen.
